# Auto select from db

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I want to do the folowing thing, here is simple select, that gets info from db.I have one db that have id/city/people.SO this is like some example selects

```
  Select1|Select2|
    City1   |2    
    City2   |Poeple2      
    City3   |People3      
    City4   |People1        
    City5   |PopleFromFirstCity
```

Here is what i want to do, when i select some city from the first select, i want in the second select that is Select2 the output to be auto changet to what i picket in the first, so if i pick City1, the second select to have **PeopleFromFirstCity** and **People1**

Comment: This makes very little sense.  Can you be more clear?

Comment: Your question is very vague and it is difficult to see *any* relationship between 'City1' and 'People1'.  Perhaps if you explain the relationships between Select1 and Select2, it might help people answer your question.

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense to me. I am Assuming you haven't normalised the database. Do you have 2 tables with cities in one table and people in another?

Comment: i have table with column with cityes and column with the people

Comment: If all the data are in one table, there is no need to have two select boxes. If it is true, that cityX has only one PersonX (and vice versa), but if it is true that CityX has PersonX, PersonY, PersonZ, then You'd have to split the table into two tables regarding the 3NF to be accomplished... You would then have one table with columns id|city and a second table with columns id|city_id|person and with relation Persons.city_id -> Cities.id. After that You can use JavaScript (AJAX) to load all the persons from the city selected in first select and make them the options of second select...

Comment: then why dont you select like SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE city = 'city1'. Which will return the people and city that you selected.

Comment: i want to be automatic, so i just asked, my way to do it its with hash, but i want to see if someone have somethig in hand to show up, but still thanks

Comment: That can be automatic only with ajax. I write some code and posted it as answer. Take a look, and make chnages. That works automatic. You select city from selection box, and persons show up. I hope that code posted as answer will help you to realize that. I tested it for syntax errors, and tested code for another tables which I have on my localhost. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first selection make this:

```
 <form>
 Select city: <select name="cities" onchange="showCity(this.value)">
 <option value="0">Chose city...</option>
 <?php          
 $sql="SELECT id,city FROM table1 ORDER BY ID DESC";      
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo"<option value=" . $row[id] . ">" . $row[city] . "</option>";
 }
 ?>
 </select></form>
```

For output from selection2 make div:

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

Now make second table table2 which contain peoples, and make .js file

```
var xmlhttp;

function showCity(str)
{
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
{
alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
return;
}
var url="http://fullpathtoselection2file/selection2.php"; // Example: http://www.site.com/files/selection2.php
url=url+"?q="+str;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return null;
}
```

Implement to your file where is selection 1 this js file. 
And now make selection 2:

```
<?php
// Get city id
$q=$_GET["q"];
// Select from SQL where city = city id
$sql="SELECT peoples,city_id FROM table2 WHERE city_id = '".$q."' order by id desc";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

// echo it
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['peoples'];
}
```

How you have 2 tables. table1 for cities second table2 for peoples. When you update your database for example from admin panel, u need to update 2 tables. for peoples and for cities.
For table 1 need to contain: id, city... Table 2 need to contain id,peoples, city_id.

Code isn't tested.